# H and K are distinct subgroups of a group G with |H| = |K| = 11. Prove that the intersection of H and K is {e}

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a group $G$ with $H$ doesn't equal to $K$ and $|H| = |K| = 11$. Prove that $H \cap K = \{e\}$

Have no idea about this question. Dont know if there is some theorem about it.

Comment: Hint: Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: Can we generalize this post for a prime $p$ so that this shall be a good original for subsequent posts?

Comment: @KannappanSampath: That seems like a good idea.  Would it be considered impolite for you to just go ahead and change it?

Comment: @TaraB It would be impolite. May be, I would make a meta post in the near future. Thank you for dropping by to tell me what you feel. I'd ping you when I write a question at the meta. Regards,

Answer (score 14):

**Hint:** $H\cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$. What can you say about the subgroups of a group of prime order?

Comment: I see. Then this question is just so easy.